# "Maximum file size was exceeded" throws by System.Net.FtpClient

Tags: c#, sftp, ftp-client, codeplex

I am facing a problem when user uploads a file with size more than 50 MB. FTP code is throwing exception "Maximum file size was exceeded".

I have placed code below.

```
if (ftp.IsConnected)
{
    var destPath = Convert.ToString(Session["fullpath"]);
    int BUFFER_SIZE = file.ContentLength; // 64KB buffer
    byte[] buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    using (Stream readStream = file.InputStream)
    using (Stream writeStream = ftp.OpenWrite(string.Format("{0}/{1}", destPath, file.FileName)))
    {
        while (readStream.Position < readStream.Length)
        {
            buffer.Initialize();
           int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
           writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }
        ViewState["fileContentLenght"] = file.ContentLength;
        writeStream.Flush();

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems more likely that this is a server limit that you're hitting rather than something you can resolve in your code.

Comment: why negative votes I have searched a lot but not found any solution

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose if it's the C# code or if it's the server, open a command prompt and use command line FTP to PUT the same file to the server. If the server errors out and returns a 400 or 500 level error during the PUT, it's a server file size limitation.

If it's determined that it is a server side limitation, you should contact the FTP server admin and see if they can't increase your upload limits on the server.